# How can I remove an ACL (eg. when user/object gets removed)?

Tags: symfony, acl

In symfony 2 documentation, they talked about adding ACLs but how can I remove them? When users or objects gets removed for example?

**UPDATE**

I was looking at the source `Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Dbal\AclProvider`, but I didn't find functions like `updateAcl`, so perhaps thats not the class? Where can I find outr what class Symfony uses and use the approperiate function to remove ACE?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently wrote up a small blog post on this with a simple ACL Manager class to help with the ACL layer.

Check it out at http://blog.codingninja.com.au/2011/12/revoke-acl-permissions-in-symfony/

Comment: useful as an example as well, +1

Answer (score 1):

The class shuld be `Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Dbal\MutableAclProvider`. The delete method is `public void deleteAcl(ObjectIdentityInterface $oid)`
http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Dbal/MutableAclProvider.html#method_deleteAcl

Comment: That's helpfull but how do I also delete corresponding identity object?? If it remains it may cause trouble when you attempt to create identity object for newly added domain object.